# nhibernate: join tables for order by

Tags: c#, sql, c#-4.0, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have an interesting scenario. I have 2 tables say 'Order' and 'Delivery'.

Order has columns- Orderid, Numberofunits , personID , cost ,orderdate, status

Delivery's Columns- DeliveryID , address, Deliverydate , personID

personID does not have a one to many (or many to many ) property.

mappings and classes of 'order' and 'delivery' are part of the bigger project which cannot be changed.( changing this would mess up lot of other parts of the project.)

Now i have a query

```
Order orderalias = null;
var order = session.QueryOver<Order>(() => orderalias  )
                               .Where(() => orderalias .Status == orderalias .Ready)
                               .OrderBy(() =>orderalias.orderdate).Asc
                               .Take(4)
                               .List();
```

But i have to order by deliverydate joing 2 tables. I tried using joinalias but obviously does not allow me to do it. (i got not an association: error)

I tried using 'WithSubquery.WhereExists' but i cannot use deliverydate outside subquery. Is there a way i can join and order this without changing the mapping and the class ?

I would like the query to be like

```
    select delivery.* from delivery 
    join order on order.personID = delivery.personId
    where order.status = 'ready'
    order by order.orderdate, delivery.deliverydate
```